# Como extrair apenas a última sequência de palavras depois de um caracter que se repete?

Tags: regex

Eu preciso extrair a última sequência de palavras em uma string como a seguinte:

```
/APP/LG/RandomFlow/ButtonOne
```

Em python, eu simplesmente usaria um *Positive Lookbehind*, como no exemplo a seguir:

```py
word = /APP/LG/RandomFlow/ButtonOne
re.findall(r'(?<=/)\w+',word)[-1]
```

No entanto, estou fazendo essa operação no Google Data Studio, que não tem *lookarounds* no seu flavor de regex.

Uma alternativa então foi usar `([^/])\w+$`, mas essa regex pega apenas a primeira letra da última palavra.

Como faço para pegar todas as letras depois do último caracter '/' sem usar lookarounds e nem métodos de string (como `split`)?

Comment: A expressão regular que você tem já está quase funcionando, basta remover o grupo de captura (que ali não faz nada): `re.search(r'[^\/]\w+$', word).group(0)` retorna a string `ButtonOne`.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Na verdade somente `\w+$` seria o suficiente (ele só não verifica se tem uma barra antes, conforme resposta abaixo). Se a string terminar, por exemplo, com "@abc", o `[^/]\w+$` pega `@abc` - claro que se essa situação não ocorre, aí tanto faz, mas ainda prefiro deixar somente `\w` já que o `[^/]` acaba ficando redundante

Comment: Aliás, em Python não precisa de regex, poderia ser `word[word.rfind('/') + 1:]` (e talvez incluir uma verificação se `rfind` não retornou `-1` antes de pegar o slice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pegar simplesmente todos os `\w` que estão no final da string:

```
\w+$
```

Afinal, o [atalho `\w`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) só considera letras, dígitos e o caractere `_`. Como ele não inclui a barra, e o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` indica o final da string, então a regex acima vai pegar a palavra que está no final da string.

O detalhe é que a regex não verifica se tem uma barra antes. Para fazer isso sem *lookarounds*, uma alternativa seria usar [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
/(\w+)$
```

Repare que `\w+` está entre parênteses, e isso cria um grupo de captura. E como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o grupo 1.

Portanto, bastaria pegar o grupo 1. A [documentação do Google Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) não é muito clara, mas segundo [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53382789), ao usar `REGEXP_EXTRACT` o retorno é o conteúdo do grupo de captura, então a regex acima serviria.

---

Este comportamento (de retornar o conteúdo do grupo de captura) parece se confirmar com base na sua regex: `([^/])\w+$` - repare que somente o `[^/]` está dentro de parênteses (e portanto, dentro do grupo de captura). Como esta expressão significa "um caractere que não é `/`" (**somente um** caractere), isso explica porque ele pega somente a primeira letra da última palavra.